# unable to add data in picker view through nsmutablearray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

i am loading data from database in nsmutableaaray

```
-(void)SeoPickerData
{

    self.pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    {
        const char *sql = "select * from Main";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;

        int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, sql, -1, &selectStatement, NULL);
        if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK)

        {
            //loop all the rows returned by the query.
            while(sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                //int   key = sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 0);
                NSString    *Term   = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2)];

                Container *myObject=[[Container alloc] InitWithTermId:Term];
                [self.pickerArray addObject:myObject];
                [myObject release];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database1) );
        }

    }

}
```

and i copy data in of array with another array like this

```
localArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Container *classObj = [[Container alloc] init];

[classObj.seoArray removeAllObjects];

[classObj SeoPickerData];

//[localArray addObject:@"Red"];

self.localArray = classObj.pickerArray;

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

when the array is load in uipickerview function like this

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    return [localArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

the error is accrued ,how can i add items in uipicker view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible error:

```
NSString    *Term   = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2)];

Container *myObject=[[Container alloc] InitWithTermId:Term];
[self.pickerArray addObject:myObject];
[myObject release];
```

You're adding `Container` objects to the array.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [localArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Then you return a `Container` object when you're expected to return an `NSString`.